# Semantically correct way to define an empty anchor

Tags: javascript, html, semantics

I want to know which form of the following structures is the one that's semantically correct, if I want to use an achor that triggers a javascript callback but doesn't make the window navigate to another place:

The javascript:

```javascript
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('AuxAnchor').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // Do something
        e.preventDefault(); // Don't navigate to anywhere
    }, false)
}, false);
```

The HTML:

Defined href attribute with blank value:

```html
<a id="AuxAnchor" href="">Click me</a>
```

Defined href attribute with missing in-document ID:

```html
<a id="AuxAnchor" href="#">Click me</a>
```

Undefined href attribute:

```html
<a id="AuxAnchor">Click me</a>
```

Note that in the latter (undefined href attribute) I have to *simulate* an hyperlink appearance by using styles, but that's basically just a cosmetic issue, and it doesn't bother me at all to do so.

Comment: Semantically, you can only have one unique id.  I think you want to change it to a class instead.

Comment: The id is the same because I just want to show the different cases, they're not intended to be on the same document at the same time.

Comment: I prefer not use `href` at all, when I don't need it..

Comment: Asking for “semantically correct” way is opinion-based and, besides, not a well-defined question. “Semantically” means “as relates to meaning”, but what “meaning” would this be about?

Comment: The semantic standards of an HTML document of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All options are correct in HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html

If you want to cover different angles of the question, check a bit accessibility (people with disabilities) guidelines:

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR35.html

Comment: Ok, so basically if I will be using an anchor that doesn't navigate I would be using the `'#'`, but the document also suggests the use of method calling by advocation (`onclick`), which use I thought was heavily discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, it's fine to simply define an `<a></a>` with no attributes at all.
Referencing the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html):

> Authors may also create an `A` element that specifies no anchors, i.e.,
>   that doesn't specify `href`, `name`, or `id`.

Answer (score 0):

> In HTML 4.01, the  tag could be either a hyperlink or an anchor. In
>   HTML5, the  tag is always a hyperlink, but if it has no href
>   attribute, it is only a placeholder for a hyperlink.
>
> HTML5 has some new attributes, and some HTML 4.01 attributes are no
>   longer supported.